# I have two master table and one mapping table. now how to update the mapping table data using prisma and node js

Tags: node.js, psql, prisma

Two master models

```
model industries {
  id                String              @id @default(uuid())
  name              String              @unique @map("name")
  isActive          Boolean             @default(true) @map("is_active")
  createdAt         DateTime            @default(now()) @map("created_at")
  updatedAt         DateTime            @default(now()) @map("updated_at")
  sectorIndustryMap sectorIndustryMap[]

  @@map("industry")
}

model sector {
  id                String              @id @default(uuid())
  name              String
  isActive          Boolean             @default(true) @map("is_active")
  createdAt         DateTime            @default(now()) @map("created_at")
  updatedAt         DateTime            @default(now()) @map("updated_at")
  sectorIndustryMap sectorIndustryMap[]
}
```

above two table is mapping with `sectorIndustryMap` table
The `sectorIndustryMap` Table is

```
model sectorIndustryMap {
  id         String     @id @default(uuid())
  sectorId   String     @map("sector_id")
  industryId String     @map("industry_id")
  createdAt  DateTime   @default(now()) @map("created_at") @db.Timestamp(6)
  industry   industries @relation(fields: [industryId], references: [id])
  sector     sector     @relation(fields: [sectorId], references: [id])

  @@unique([sectorId, industryId])
  @@map("sector_industry_map")
}
```

how to update `industryId` in the sectorIndustryMap table using prisma and node js

```
async update(id,sectorId,newData) {
   const industry = await prisma.sectorIndustryMap.update({
      where:{
        id
      },
      data:{
        sectorId:sectorId,
        industry:{
          update:{
            ...newData
          }
        }
      },
      include:{
        industry:true
      }
    })
    this.data = industry;
    return industry;
  }
}
```

above node code is update function
this function is throwing some error like `` Unknown arg `sectorId` in data.sectorId for type sectorIndustryMapUpdateInput. Did you mean `sector`? ``
What should I do?